# iOS 5: NSConcreteValue _wantsForwardingFromResponder:toNextResponder:withEvent:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception, ios5

Any hint about what can be the cause for this error? Or from where to start?

```
[NSConcreteValue _wantsForwardingFromResponder:toNextResponder:withEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

It happens only with iOS 5 ( both simu and device)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was all about using a NSValue object where I should't. 
If you have some NSConcreteValue exception problem, just look for some improper use of NSValue class in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an address for an object is being reused on account of memory management issues. Trying turning  [`NSZombieEnabled`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) on and see which object you are over-releasing.